# Nodejs, how to deploy typescript project which reference multiple local projects to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku, deployment

I have a nodejs typescript project with this package.json:

```
{
"name": "construction-node-service",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Fine Chat App Nodejs Service",
"main": "app.js",
"types": "./@types",
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "debug": "nodemon --inspect  src/app.ts",
  "dev:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon.json --inspect-brk src/index.ts",
  "tsdebug": "ts-node-dev --respawn ",
  "tsdev": "nodemon --exec ts-node tt.ts",
  "compile": "tsc && node dist/app.js",
  "dev": "nodemon -e ts  --exec npm run compile",
  "dev:server": "nodemon --watch ./**/*.ts --exec ts-node src/app.ts",
  "start": "node dist/app.js"
},
"engines": {
  "node": "12.22.1"
},
"author": "Ayman Shokry",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "@types/compression": "^1.7.0",
  "bson-objectid": "^2.0.1",
  "compression": "^1.7.4",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "generate-unique-id": "^2.0.1",
  "global-shared-node": "file:../../../public-api/NodeJs/global-shared-node",
  "public-dao-node": "file:../../../public-api/NodeJs/public-dao-node",
  "helmet": "^4.6.0",
  "moment": "^2.29.1",
  "mongoose": "^5.12.1",
  "multer": "^1.4.2",
  "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
  "sequelize": "^6.6.2",
  "sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.0",
  "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
  "@types/node": "^15.0.1",
  "@types/sequelize": "^4.28.9",
  "@types/validator": "^13.1.3",
  "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "pm2": "^4.5.0",
  "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
  "sequelize-cli": "^5.5.1",
  "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
  "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.6",
  "typescript": "^4.2.4"
}
}
```

I thought if I can copy the 2 local project src files to my project src folder before deploy but I think this solution is annoying

as you see  I referenced 2 local projects on my HDD the question is how can I deploy this project with the 2 project dependencies to Heroku.thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the questions and suggestions on the internet, the answer is NO.

According to many communities and experts, Heroku's model is to run one app per dyno (and often many dynos for a single app).

But wait, there is a case in which two servers are deployed to a single dyno and it worked too. You can check it here: https://medium.com/@nadayar/heroku-fu-multiple-servers-on-one-dyno-6fc68d57b373

Hope this solves your problem!